# VS Code "Extension host terminated unexpectedly"

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm always receiving the error message:

> Extension host terminated unexpectedly

when using Visual Studio Code as the picture shows.

[image: Extension_host_terminated_unexpectedly.png]

I was wondering what to do with it. Many people suggested that I remove the "git" folder, but it doesn't work. This is what "Developer tools" shows:

[image: Developer_tools.png]

Comment: Could you give more information on when the error occurs? This would help to answer your question.

Comment: I can see no relation with git in the error message. Can you give more information on how git is related to your question or remove the tag?

Comment: You probably have installed one or more extensions that bring down your vscode process. Remove all your manually installed extensions and see if vscode goes back to normal. Then add them back one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

I find out the reason behind the notification **"Extension host terminated unexpectedly."**
when we install VSCode ( from the official link (with the recent updates as well ) ) into our system most of the Antiviruses deletes two files from the folders.

[ C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node ]

AND

[C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\worker]

These two files get deleted by Antiviruses

1 ) **extensionHostProcess.js**
Address:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js

2 ) **extensionHostWorker.js**
Address:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\worker\extensionHostWorker.js

**The SOLUTION is:** [ Well I'm using Quick Heal Antiviruses But Steps are the same for most of the Antiviruses ]

1. Open Antiviruses then click on the "Scan Options", look for the " Quarantine & Backup " option click on it,
2. Then click on " view files ",
3. Then from the list of quarantined files restore both the files [ extensionHostProcess.js And extensionHostWorker.js ] individually by clicking on the restore button,
4. Make shower you click in a check box " Add this to exclusion list ",
5. Then click on " Yes ".

Well, my problem has been solved by this method.